# Getting error while running new flutter error in Android studio Electric Eel

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\sanje\AndroidStudioProjects\weather_app\android\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\sanje\AndroidStudioProjects\weather_app\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\sanje.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\cusw5g2nbmmntllzldoslifyq).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You can update distrubution url in `gradle-wrapper.properties` as
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip`.